# Sending Salesforce data to map in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I am working on acquiring a Salesforce mapping license. As far as I can tell, this would allow data within my ArcGIS Online account to be viewable in a map in Salesforce. What I cannot tell is whether I would be able to take geocoded information from Salesforce, and connect via this license back to ArcGIS Online to have the information display on a map within ArcGIS Online.

How do I connect ArcGIS Online and Salesforce, and have both of the platforms speak to each other?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380307&type=1

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it will let you consume SF data is arcgis apps, just arcgis data in SF app with any other SF objects that have a geolocation field. I remember seeing an option to sync features to an arcgis layer but that’s not really the same thing as consuming the data live from arcgis apps. I have accomplished consuming SF live data directly using Koop with minimal coding. I found the SF maps product very limited with regard to the things from arcgis online we could expose, and a lot work had to be done configure things like symbols from within SF, which we cant expect our SF staff to do. We needed to have many web maps and apps embedded is SF. Using Koop allowd me to bring SF data into arcgis and configure web maps and apps as if it was a feature service. Then we embed these apps either as simple iframes or custom lightning components with Arcgis maps sdk. Still a work in progress I can report back as I do more.